# ¿Cómo hacer que currencyPipe.transform transforme el precio a numero entero y hasta 2 decimales en Angular?

Tags: angular

Necesito que desde el **input** cuando el usuario vaya ingresando el **precio**, el **currencyPipe** lo vaya transformando automaticamente, por ejemplo que permita escribir **1500,25** o 1500 sin decimales.
De la forma que lo tengo hecho es utilizando el **currencyPipe en el valueChanges del formControl price** no da resultado ya que si el usuario quisiera escribir 1500 automaticamente se transforma en 1,500.
y si ademas quisiera escribir 1500,25 lo transforma a 150,025.

**component.ts**

```js
import { CurrencyPipe } from '@angular/common';

constructor(
    private currencyPipe: CurrencyPipe,
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder
  ) {
    this.buildForm();
    // cuando escribe el precio
    this.form.valueChanges.subscribe(formulario => {
      if (formulario.price){
        this.form.patchValue({
          price: this.currencyPipe.transform(formulario.price.replace(/\D/g, '').replace(/^0+/, ''), '', '', '1.0-0')
        }, {emitEvent: false});
      }
    });
  }

buildForm() {
    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      name: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(50)]],
      year: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.min(1500),Validators.max(this.year)]],
      author: ['', [Validators.required]],
      category: ['', [Validators.required]],
      editorial: ['', [Validators.required]],
      description: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(2500)]],
      quantity: ['', [Validators.required]],
      price: ['', [Validators.required]],
      image: [''],
      state: [true]
    });
  }
```

**component.html** (solo muestro el **input del precio** que es el que importa para ahorrar codigo)

```html
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <div class="form-group col-md-6 mb-3">
    <input             
      class="form-control"
      formControlName="price"
      step="0.01"
      [(ngModel)]="book.price"
      placeholder="Precio $"
    />
    <div *ngIf="form.get('price').errors &&  form.get('price').dirty">
       <p
         class="text-center mt-1"
         *ngIf="form.get('price').hasError('required')"
       >
    <small class="text-danger">Este campo es obligatorio!</small>
       </p>
    </div>
 </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes lograr esto fácilmente con la libreria [`ngx-mask`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-mask)

```
 <input
      type="text"             
      class="form-control"
      formControlName="price"
      mask="separator.2"
      prefix="$ "
      thousandSeparator=","
    />
```

Básicamente convierte un string al formato deseado y te devuelve una cadena limpia. Hay que notar que el input debe ser `type="text"` para que funcione.

Te dejo un [ejemplo funcional aquí](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-yrw18p?file=src/app/hello.component.html)

Comment: Excelente Legna, era justo lo que necesitaba muchas gracias!